# How to COALESCE two fields in the same one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, coalesce

So, I have 2 fields, `Other_EEs`, and `Other_EE_Names` from the same table. I want to merge both into one existing field in another table without any interruption. Both contain a bit of info. So far I merged those two fields separately but the second one overrides the first one. How can I merge two fields at the same time? Here's what I'm using so far. Thanks!

```
UPDATE MI
   SET MI.M_Reps_Contact_Info = M.Other_EE_Names + ' '+ M.Other_EEs +
                                COALESCE( MI.M_Reps_Contact_Info + 
                                          CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' )
  FROM dbo.suptbl_Sprint2_Interview AS M
 INNER JOIN dbo.suptbl_Sprint2_MgrInterview AS MI 
    ON M.Junction_ID = MI.Junction_ID`
```

Comment: Can you show sample data and output?  I don't see any problem with this, unless the two `Other_EE` fields have `NULL` values.

Comment: @Goat CO the resulting output is the second field's data, which means whichever gets pushed last gets merged. Both fields have some data in them.

Comment: Some sample data and desired output might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second one "overrides" the first, then I am guessing that the values can be NULL.

Try this `set` statement:

```
SET MI.M_Reps_Contact_Info = COALESCE(M.Other_EE_Names + ' ', '') +
                             COALESCE(M.Other_EEs, '') +
                             COALESCE(MI.M_Reps_Contact_Info + 
                                      CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' )
```

Comment: Thanks! It's doing the job but the resulting out is repetitive. Now how do I stop this to keep repeating the data?

Comment: Ok scratch the repetitive data! It looks like it's because I ran the UPDATE statement many times! So this  was my solution:

`UPDATE MI
SET MI.M_Reps_Contact_Info = COALESCE(M.Other_EE_Names + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') + 
       COALESCE(M.Other_EEs + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') +
       COALESCE(MI.M_Reps_Contact_Info, '')
FROM dbo.suptbl_Sprint2_Interview AS M
INNER JOIN dbo.suptbl_Sprint2_MgrInterview AS MI 
 ON M.Junction_ID = MI.Junction_ID`

P.S. "CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)" because of line-breaks